# Is it possible to login as root user in LXDE desktop environment?

Tags: fedora, lxde

Is it possible to configure certain settings to allow me to login as root user into the GUI on a Fedora 17 with an LXDE desktop?

I know I can do it using KDE, but KDE is not an option for this particular machine.

I do understand the risk of logging in as root user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though this is a bad idea yes it is possible. The fastest method would be to do a Ctl+Alt+F1 and login as root. If there is no root password then login as a regular user and do the sudo su. After that you can use top to find and kill the xserver. Lastly run startx which should put you at a graphical desktop.

This is a very bad idea. If you need to run graphical applications to run as root and you do not want to mess with the gnome utility to do so then simply sudo su into a root shell from your terminal then run it from there. for example "/~> nautilus" this is how I manage files that need root permission and it works well.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me, on fedora 19 at least, that root login in LXDE is prevented by a pam configuration.  The file `/etc/pam.d/lxde` contains the line

```
auth       required    pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet
```

Which clearly indicates that the root user is silently refused to log in.  Commenting out this line immediately causes lxdm to allow root to log in.

On Fedora 22 LXDE spin, the file is named "lxdm" rather than "lxde."

Answer (score 0):

Ahh this article does the trick properly

http://www.tejasbarot.com/2010/04/23/login-as-a-root-from-gui-fedora-13

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Better to include some answer text here and provide the link as backup. As it stands your answer has no value if the link becomes broken